# erro em clonar repositorio do bitbucket pelo ssh

Tags: git, ssh

Eu segui os passos [desse site](http://www.maiconschmitz.com.br/blog/2014/07/07/configurando-chaves-ssh-para-acessar-o-bitbucket-no-ubuntu.html) para poder acessar o Bitbucket via SSH no Ubuntu. Porém quando eu terminei e tentei clonar um repositório o terminal imprimiu esse erro:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.2' to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Então eu gostaria de saber porque o erro? E o que fazer para corrigir?

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um erro genérico que diz que a chave que foi usada para conectar não foi reconhecida pelo servidor externo. Normalmente quer dizer que você cometeu algum erro na hora de configurar sua chave pública lá no Bitbucket.

Siga a última parte do passo-a-passo de novo e deve resolver.